# CURL IMAP APPEND command

Tags: curl, imap

I would like to use CURL in order to APPEND emails at the given date.

```
$ curl -kv -u user@vm.org:user 'imap://IP:143' -X 'APPEND INBOX (Mon, 7 Feb > 1994 21:52:25 +0000) {310}' '
Date: Mon, 7 Feb 1994 21:52:25 -0800 (PST)
From: Fred Foobar <foobar@Blurdybloop.COM>
Subject: afternoon meeting
To: mooch@owatagu.siam.edu
Message-Id: <B27397-0100000@Blurdybloop.COM>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: TEXT/PLAIN; CHARSET=US-ASCII
               C:
Hello Joe, do you think we can meet at 3:30 tomorrow?'
```

Unfortunately, it's not working, as the email is not passed to the server

```
C: A003 APPEND (Mon, 7 Feb 1994 21:52:25 +0000) INBOX {310}
S: A003 BAD Missing required argument to Append
```

I also try by sending the email as a file:

```
$ curl -kv -u user@vm.org:user 'imap://IP:143' -X 'APPEND INBOX (Mon, 7 Feb > 1994 21:52:25 +0000) {310}' -T email.txt
```

but it still not working

```
C: A003 APPEND email.txt (\Seen) {318}
S: A003 NO [TRYCREATE] Mailbox does not exist
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have to provide the IMAP command, CURL will do that for you.
However you have to specify on which folder you're working on.

```
curl -kv imaps://user:pwd@mail.server.org/INBOX -T ~/simple.eml
```

see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/imap-append.html